# Https abuse in public place

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, ssl, https, openwrt

I'm helping my friend to fight crime , after in pub using free wi-fi several times she got abuses , she somehow reported ip's and got rid from problems , after an 10th time I went there installed on router Open WRT since it open source just for future modifications on this problem , luckily router supported just compiled code , also that was better interface. Well ok normal, I just went there and put it , later she asked can you monitor that https sessions to help me ? I said no it's impossible it's encrypted! Now i'm just transferring URLS LOGS to my server and later to my mail box. After another abuse when someone over https season stole some stuff from ebay , it became serious. All I have ip's, and that's all, If we switch off HTTPS even Facebook will be not accessible , we will loose something about like 20% of income, just switching off https or blocking specific ports, we now forced to solve this problem. We have all access to all routers however we can't interact what happens in their "https" we need to have it in plain! We have forwarded for quote all code from https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt to an "IT sector gurus" , however they refused start work without upfront (5K$/monthly , without even known outcome, but with refund on 80% on research after undelivered solution)

My question is pretty simple , how to have fake https sessions or force them to have on our "server" unencoded to overcome this and again we have open source software  ? so we can filter out after coding router software , to have ability block in content words like "child porn" and block it , from our keyword library which we develope. I can't afford without any bold people comments help for such basic things for my friend, who's gonna be ripped out with initial 5K 
https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt

We have normally about 60-90 sessions at peak, SMS registration or and id proof will just scare away both abusers and old clients who want to just calm here like always.

Big thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is pretty simple , how to have fake https sessions or force them to have on our "server" unencoded to overcome this and again we have open source software

You can't do this really well without cooperation from connecting clients.  The right way to do this is require clients to install a MITM HTTPS certificate, have an HTTPS proxy that uses this certificate, and then require clients to install this certificate to access HTTPS.  Companies can do this easily and transparently to the end user because things like certificates can be pushed out via Windows Active Directory and such.

> so we can filter out after coding router software , to have ability block in content words like "child porn" and block it , from our keyword library which we develope.

Based on some of the words of your question, it sounds like you are running a business and offering Wifi as an amenity.

You really need to talk to a lawyer and find out what your legal liabilities are with offering public Internet service, and act accordingly.

If you are simply providing public Internet access, whether or not you are liable for traffic flowing through it, and to what extent, is a legal matter - and by trying to block unwanted traffic, you could be exposing yourself to additional liability, more so than if you did nothing at all.

You may want to talk to your ISP and see what options they have for business-class public hotspots.  It may be cheaper than doing it yourself and will offload the liability and other issues like security, etc. to your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You were right the first time: "No it's impossible, it's encrypted!". If every random pub or restaurant could snoop on their customers' HTTPS traffic, HTTPS would be terribly broken.

The best you can do is block access to sites with names you don't like. Even the HTTPS (TLS) headers leak the name of the website the client is trying to connect to, so I'm sure someone makes a firewall that looks at those server identity strings in the TLS handshake and blocks the TLS handshake from completing if the user is trying to connect to an unauthorized site.

However, this doesn't help you when people are using your public Wi-Fi hotspot to do abusive things on popular websites like eBay or Facebook that you'd never want to block. There's really no way for you to see what people are doing on those sites, short of making all your users install special proxy certificates and settings as if they were working in a mega-corporation that wants to spy on all their traffic. But if you don't want your regulars to have to personally authentication, you're definitely not going to ask them to install a bunch of proxy settings and trusted certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to intercept the HTTPS traffic you are fighting an uphill battle and will probably piss off your clients and breach trust.  As others have mentioned you would need to get clients to install a certificate which would allow you to MITM the traffic (which has side effects and can break things), or force them to use a proxy server.

Of-course there are other ways of tackling the problem of fraud without MITM'ing the connection.  You can require users register their device (ie MAC address) with you, and then keep a track of when that MAC address connects to your network and with what IP address.  Combined with raw data logs of (encrypted) sessions, if fraud is reported back to you, you can match it back to the MAC address and thus the originating user - Unfortunately this is not trivial to implement.

Another partial solution - which won't allow you to see what is being viewed, but will give you some small insites and could help you reduce what you log - could be to sniff DNS queries to see what sites users are connecting to.